# Android Rotate only the keyboard 180 degrees?

Tags: java, android

I have an app which essentially splits the screen into two halves, with one half rotated 180 degrees.  Both halves are symmetrical, but also contain edit text fields that the user will input text into.  Is it possible to rotate only the keyboard 180 degrees so the user on the rotated half can input text properly?

Comment: so the user sees  the text being inputted sideways?

Comment: 180 degrees, so it would be normal.  To the other user it would be upside down.

Comment: right, sorry. so you want to input text so if faces outward?

Comment: With how it is normally, it comes out of the bottom of the screen.  Is it possible so that when the rotated edit text is focused, the keyboard comes out of the top of the screen, rotated 180 degrees?

Comment: Assuming you are doing some type of two-player game: you may want to look at a custom keyboard view with an appropriate View.setRotation() value. See this article on building your own custom keyboard view: http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Comment: you want the keyboard to be on the top of the screen? that does not sound very convenient.

Comment: @njzk2 I don't think you're quite grasping the concept.

Comment: apparently not. may be with an illustration of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you could just let the whole UI rotate and just swap the contents of the UI elements on the opposite sides. Since they are "symmetrical" the user doesn't know if it's `EditTextAbc` or `EditTextXyz` that's on his side at any given time. You would just have to also swap all the UI element listeners like `OnClickListeners` and what ever you might have. Maybe a bit awkward. But it's an idea...